# How can I get space between these icons?

Tags: html, css, icons

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="github" src="GitHub-Mark-64px.png" alt="github logo">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="github" src="GitHub-Mark-64px.png" alt="github logo">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="github" src="GitHub-Mark-64px.png" alt="github logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Picture my icons and what they look like now -

[image: Picture my icons and what they look like now]

As far as CSS goes I have tried using justify content with space around but it spreads them to far apart. I have also tried playing around with padding and margin and it does not not seem to be doing anything. Do I have the html not set up correctly or am I doing something wrong with the css?

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show the code.

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: One simplest way is to add `margin` for the `<a>` elements that you have in CSS. But these elements are `inline` elements, so you need to make them non-inline by making them block, inline-block, inline-table etc. eg: `display: inline-block`. Check this for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin.

Answer (score 0):

Margins works pretty fine.

```css
/* You can use this */
a:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Or this */
a:not(:last-of-type) img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/64">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/64">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/64">
    </a>
</div>
```

Also there are many other ways to do it, so if it is not working in your environment it's issue with that and that cannot be debugged here.

Comment: On my css I only had .icons so I added , .github and then margin worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: 1 for using `a:not(:last-of-type)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-right` to all `github` class. But not need margin-right `github` img in last  `<a>`". that is taken by

```
a:last-child .github{
  margin-right:0px;
}
.github{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```css
.icons{
  margin:20px auto;
  text-align:center;
}
a:last-child .github{
  margin-right:0px;
}
.github{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
    <a href="#"><img class="github" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0ard.png" alt="github logo" /></a> 
    <a href="#"><img class="github" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0ard.png" alt="github logo" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="github" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0ard.png" alt="github logo" /></a>
</div>
```